# Exclude branches from Jenkins multibranch job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to exclude branches to be build in multibranch job using Filter by name (with wildcards).
My goal is to build all branches except for staging and release branches.
Job configuration is:
 Include: *
 Exclude: staging release

From some reason exclude section doesn't work and the job includes staging and release branches as well.

Comment: Are you sure you input correct branch names to exclude section ? They have to be exactly the same as in source control.

Comment: 100% sure. if it makes any difference I'm using Bitbucket Project.

Comment: I am having the same problem and trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think your "problem" is that your branch pipeline view still displays old items. These are called "orphaned" items.If you scroll down in your multibranch config you will notice a section called "**Orphaned Item Strategy**"

Tick the checkbox "Discard old items". You can leave the input fields empty.

Comment: Discard old items is ticked. when I scan Multibranch Pipeline both branches are not skipped in the scan log.